# Is the fact of consciousness moving through time compatible with a block universe?

Tags: reference-request, consciousness, time

We all experience consciousness as moving through time. I wonder, is that fact compatible with a block universe? I actually do believe in the block universe, but I wonder if any philosopher has found a way to make both the block universe and changing consciousness compatible. This problem of the seeming incompatibility between the two has really bothered me for a while, and I would like to see it resolved.

Comment: Why do you chose to believe in the block Universe if it is fundamentally at odds with your conscious experience?

Comment: "conscious moving through time" is nor trivial nor "fact" (i never "experienced" "future", neither "presence/now" (it is very "unreal",..."volatile"..."faster changing than i can think") ..what remains is "my memory" of "thinking now"....

Comment: we all (more or less consciously) can experience "our body(ies)" in "relation to" "time and  location and other "beings"" ... but "in fantasy" ("ideal consciousness"...no "body", "free (rw/ff/pause/stop/off) time")), time (and space) plays only sub-ordinate role!?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question reminds me of another asked recently about whether philosophers are sometimes guilty of forgetting Occam's razor when they speculate metaphysically about matters well-described by science. You might find it easier to reconcile your conscious experience with time if you imagine time as it is treated in mainstream physics. In that view, time is part of a 4D spacetime in which you exist at any given moment at a localised point. A moment later you exist at  different point, and a moment after that at yet another, and so on. If you join the dots between all of the points at which you successively exist, they form a trajectory known as a world line. The temporal interval between any two events on your world line is a 'proper time', and we can quantify it using any well-behaved clock. You experience yourself moving through time because in the sense in which I have just described it you are moving through time. I appreciate that view might cause you to have to rethink your metaphysical assumptions, but that might not be a bad thing if they are an unnecessary adornment, as far as Special Relativity is concerned, and clash with your personal experience of time.

Comment: "time as it is treated in mainstream physics". It is only Relativity that explicitly pictures a block universe. It's wrong to portray science as monolithic or unified in how it regards time. Proposals for quantum-gravity theories always involves challenging the General Relativity picture because it has proved impossible to apply the principles that led to canonical quantisation of the other forces & their fields to it. Ie, what Nima Atkani-Hamed's 'doom of spacetime': the energy required to probe below the Planck length would lead to a black hole, constraining the distances that are meaningful

Comment: @CriglCragl sure, I wouldn't argue with that. But the question asked about how to reconcile our conscious experience with time, and I suggested how. The question didn't ask for a comprehensive summary of all the different perspectives on time.